# Magento 2 : CURL Use in Observer

Tags: customer, magento-2.1.3, register, curl

I am using event `customer_register_success` for sending customer detail to a third party website. I am facing problem in implementation of CURL in event observer. Do you have any example of using `CURL` in a magento 2 observer?

Comment: Can you specify which error you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its a good practice but you can follow below code in you observer for your requirement.

```
$ch = curl_init();

//pass your arguments in array
$request = array(
    'USER' => $user,
    'PWD' => $pwd,
    'SIGNATURE' => $signature,
    'METHOD' => 'RefundTransaction',
    'VERSION' => urlencode($version)
);
$api = "Your Api Url here";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($request));

//here curl request will be sent

$curlResponse = curl_exec($ch);
```

You can get your response in `$curlResponse`

Thankx

Comment: +1 for "not good practise" ;) the better way imho would be to implement a cronjob that sends this data every 5 minutes or so